# How to query DynamoDb StringSet attribute efficiently

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

i am trying to use dynamoDb in an Android app.
i have an item in a table. this item has a StringSet attribute. let's say for argument's sake, that this string set contains one million items. what is the most efficient way of getting 4 random items out of this set?
thanks
regards
clive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have one million strings in a single record, there is a per record size limitation.

This is how you can solve it.

string (PARTITION KEY), sequentialnumber (RANGE KEY), any extra attributed for this record.

Generate 4 random numbers ( 1 to 1 million ) and query for records, with the string and random number to dynamo.

This would solve your problem.

It is not efficient to search a record with million of items inside inside it.

Comment: thanks. i just used an example of 1 million records to indicate that the item has a large number of items.